# In which case will 'size > originalValue.length' in String Constructor - String(String original)?

Tags: java, string, constructor

In the String constructor's code -

```
public String(String original) {
    int size = original.count;
    char[] originalValue = original.value;
    char[] v;
    if (originalValue.length > size) {
            int off = original.offset;
            v = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalValue, off, off+size);
    } 
          .
          .
          .
  }
```

I am confused about this line:

```
 if (originalValue.length > size) {
```

In case we have something like

```
String s1 = "Abcd";
String s3 = new String(s1.substring(3));
```

then according to code

```
original = "d";
size = 1;
originalValue.length = 1;
```

So `size` and `originalValue.length` are same here.

Am I wrong here? I looked for answers but could not find any satisfactory one, so I am posting a new question for this. Please help me understand the exact case when size > originalValue.length. Thanks

Comment: That's old code. What version of Java are you looking at?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I guess he is using Jdk 1.6 .

Comment: yes JDK 1.6. Was confused with this part, s0 asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very outdated. Strings used to be able to share their underlying `char[] value`. For example when you would get the substring of a `String`

```
"a string".substring(3);
```

the String `"a string"` had a `char[]` which it shared with the `String` returned by `substring`. To do this, `String` had to maintain a `count` and an `offset` to tell it where the current `String` actually started.

So the code you see is for such a `String` so that only relevant parts of the original `String` is used in the new `String` being created.

This was changed at some point during Java 7. `String` instances no longer share their underlying `char[]`.